# How to change button color in smartclient?

Tags: smartclient

I have searched for this and found this topic but it does not have enought details:

https://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/18078-can-not-change-button-background-color

> So i think you need to create your own style, or modify the existing
> ones

How to create new style? How to add it? How to find existing ones? There are many css and some pcss files in my project but I do not get which ones are used by smartclient.

I am adding buttons this way:

```
<VLayout>
                            <HTMLFlow contents={`<span style="font-weight: bold">Actions</span><br>`}/>
                            <HTMLFlow contents={`<style></style>`}/>
                            <LayoutSpacer/>
                            {this.addNewButton = <Button title={translation.button.addNew}/>}
                            <LayoutSpacer/>
                            {this.deleteButton = <Button title={translation.button.remove} visibility={'hidden'}/>}
                        </VLayout>
```

By PhpStorm autocompletion I find there is backgroundColor property:
{this.deleteButton = <Button title={translation.button.remove} visibility={'hidden'} backgroundColor={red}/>}

But setting red this way does not work.

I have provided one answer, but it just changes background color. Need to know how to set not only background but text color, border color. Might be that I need baseStyle property but I do not see examples how to use it.

**Update**

I have another example where my provided answer does not work.

```
this._buttonSearch = <Button title={translation.button.search} width={70} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button"}/>;
            this._buttonReset = <Button title={translation.button.reset} width={70} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button"}/>;
            this._monthlyViewButton = <Button title={translation.button.monthly_view} width={80} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button view-btn"}/>;
            // this._monthlyViewButton2 = <Button title={'montly 2'} width={80} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button view-btn"}/>;
            this._weeklyViewButton = <Button title={translation.button.weekly_view} width={80} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button view-btn"}/>;
            this._dailyViewButton = <Button title={translation.button.daily_view} width={80} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button active-view-btn"}/>;
            this._previousDayButton = <Button title={translation.button.previous_day} width={102} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button"}/>;
            this._nextDayButton = <Button title={translation.button.next_day} width={77} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button"}/>;
            this._skipCheckButton = <Button title={translation.button.skip_check} width={77} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button view-btn"} backgroundColor={'white'}/>;
            this._showHideUnassigned = <Button title={translation.button.hide_unassigned} prompt={translation.button.hide_unassigned} width={120} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button"}/>;
            this._shiftViewButton = <Button title={translation.button.shift_view} width={80} autoFit baseStyle={"btn-secondary button view-btn"}/>;


            this._dynamicForm =
                <DynamicForm dataSource={page.schedules.ds.EmployeesDataSource.sc()}
                        useAllDataSourceFields={false}
                             numCols={12}
                             colWidths={["12%", "13%", "1%", "12%", "1%", "38%", "1%", "1%", "1%", "19%", "1%", "1%"]}>
                    <FormFieldItem name={"text"} showTitle={false} showHintInField={true} hint={translation.schedules.text}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name={"departments"} editorType={"ComboBoxItem"} showTitle={false} showHintInField={true} hint={translation.schedules.department}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name={"from"} title={translation.title.day} type={"date"} width={130} useTextField={true}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._buttonSearch} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._buttonReset} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._dailyViewButton} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._weeklyViewButton} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._skipCheckButton} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._monthlyViewButton} showTitle={false}/
                    <FormFieldItem name="" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._shiftViewButton} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="previousDayButton" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._previousDayButton} showTitle={false}/>
                    <FormFieldItem name="nextDayButton" editorType="CanvasItem" createCanvas={() => this._nextDayButton} showTitle={false}/>

                </DynamicForm>;
```

So there is _skipCheckButton. It should be white as _weeklyViewButton - code looks same. But for some reason it is blue. What can be causing it to be blue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While writing question and testing, I noticed that on the error I could click PhpStorm suggestion, and it created private variable red.

Then I set 'red' string to the red. And used this.red to backgroundColor property and it worked.

And then tried this way and it worked - needed to put in quotes:

```
{this.deleteButton = <Button title={translation.button.remove} visibility={'hidden'} backgroundColor={'red'}/>}
```

And about the updated part where shows blue button instead of white - the answer is - check if you are testing the right place. In my case - when clicking "Monthly" button it has probably to show blue skip check because I added just random button earlier for testing. But when clicking "Daily" button, then it had to show white button. I was testing wrong place.